# VS code extension - submenu not appearing as nested menu on editor toolbar and shows empty area when icon is not specified

Tags: vscode-extensions

I created one submenu command to be displayed on editor toolbar as nested menu
I am observing two issues
1)It is not appearing as nested menu on the editor toolbar.I can see icon for submenu command, on clicking the icon - child menus get displayed but i need submenu to show drop down arrow so that user can see it as nested menu i.e.having child menu items.

2)If there is no icon for the submenu command then it does not display any text / label.editor title bar shows empty area, hovering on empty are shows command label

Following is the code snippet for package.json file
contributes►submenus
"submenus": [
{
"id": "abcd",
"label": "NestedMenu",
"icon": ""
}
]

contributes►menus►
"abcd": [
{
"command": "cmd1",
"group": "test1@1"
},
{
"command": "cmd2",
"group": "test1@2"
}
],

contributes -> menu -> editor / title
{
"submenu": "abcd",
"group": "navigation@12",
"label": "nested menu sample",
"when": 
}